# How to remove background of a view with different Transition?

Tags: swift, swiftui, transition

I'll provide a simplified example. Let's say when I toggle I want to instantly remove the background of the text without any transition or animation, but have the text itself fade out with opacity. How can I achieve this? Please, do not suggest using a `ZStack` instead of `.background`; I am looking for a solution in this specific scenario. If it's not possible, please let me know.

```swift
struct BackgroundTransition: View {

    @State var show = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
    
            Group {
                if show {
                    Text("Some Text")
                        .background(
                            Color.blue
                                .transition(.identity)
                                .animation(.none, value: show)
                        )
    
                } else {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
    
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    show.toggle()
                }
            }
    
        }
    }

}
```

I tried applying `.identity` transition to the background view and `.none` animation, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think `.transition()` works this way. Try `.transaction { $0.animation = .none }` this allows to intercept the animation "transaction" and change it's properties for that branch of the `View` hierarchy.

Comment: tried it, still background is disappearing with opacity

Comment: I tried different things, my hunch is, because the `Color.blue` is in the `background()`, the animation pipeline takes the "before" and the "after" states and animates between them. In that case, if you can't separate the foreground and the background, you could separate the triggers if your case allows it like so: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/be83224900bc47e48fb0c6c71e87529a

Comment: Oh, there was a very similar answer already, my bad for not checking before posting :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is having **two separate variables**: one animated, the other not.

```
struct BackgroundTransition: View {

    @State var show = true
    @State var showBackground = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Group {
                
                Text("Some Text")
                    .opacity(show ? 1 : 0)
                    .background {
                        if showBackground {
                            Color.blue
                                .transition(.identity)
                        }
                    }
                
                if !showBackground {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
    
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    show.toggle()
                }
                /// Do not animate this
                showBackground.toggle()
            }
    
        }
    }

}
```

I removed the if in order to do so, otherwise all the Views inside would have been animated regardless of any other condition.
I didn't know how to handle the Spacer this case though, since it is pushing the View as soon as the toggle button is tapped.
Try this out anyway and let me know what you think!

Comment: thanks for the answer, I upvoted it, but in my actual case the text should be removed (I have complex layout transition), not just become transparent, and also the variable should be same (it is actually a binding that I pass)

Comment: If you'd like it to be removed you can maybe scale it down to zero using scale effect maybe. For the variable to be the same I don't really know how to accomplish this.